# PHP to loop a list presented in a table - I cannot understand how it works

Tags: php, html, wordpress

This is my first time modifying somebody else's WordPress theme and I cannot figure out how this code works exactly.

The following code generates a list in a table that has 3 columns and infinite rows. How does this code define the number of columns? How would I change 3 columns to 5, etc?

```
<table class="brands">
                <tbody>
                <?php if($terms): ?>
                <?php foreach($terms as $term): ?>
                <tr>
                    <?php
                        foreach($term as $tr):
                        $term_name = $tr->name;
                        $term_id = $tr->term_id;
                        $term_thumb = get_field("thumbnail","{$listing_cat}_{$term_id}");
                        $term_link = get_term_link($tr->slug,$listing_cat);
                    ?>
                        <td>
                            <a href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>">
                                <?php if($term_thumb): ?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo $term_thumb["url"]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $term_name; ?>">
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <p><?php echo $term_name; ?></p>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: I would love to see it generate, as you say `infinite rows`, if you do not understand basic stuff like foreach or for loops then start be learning this in a isolated case.

Comment: It's creating 3 columns, because there are 3 elements in the `$term` array: `foreach($term as $tr)`, which is an element of `$terms`

Comment: I used the word infinite because it was not necessary to include details about the contents of the array as that has no relevance to my problem. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
<?php

print_r($term);

foreach($term as $tr):
```

you might notice that count($term) = 3, that's why it is printing 3 columns. Well, for hainvg more columns, try push more elements in your $term.

As for "infinite rows", that rather depends on the length of your $terms array.

Answer (score 1):

Its displaying 3 columns because of the no of default $terms in the theme's database. It is running a loop for each $item, so basically for you to run 5 columns you will have to either push items to the database table or you can skip checking for $item and run a loop as

```
<table class="brands">
    <tbody>
       <?php for(i=0; i<5, i++){ ?>
              <tr>
                  <?php
                     //what you want to display
                  ?>
                    <td>
                        //your table data
                    </td>

              </tr>
       <?php }?>
   </tbody>
```